# Development to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production

I have my first app in rails running on a VPS with apache +  passenger
I want to go to production.

### My gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :production do
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'execjs'
end
```

### My production.rb

```
CGS::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

 # Code is not reloaded between requests
 config.cache_classes = true

 # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
 config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
 config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

 # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
 config.serve_static_assets = false

 # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
 config.assets.compress = true

 # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
 config.assets.compile = false

 # Generate digests for assets URLs
 config.assets.digest = true

 # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
 # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

 # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
 # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
 # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

 # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, 
 # config.force_ssl = true

 # See everything in the log (default is :info)
 # config.log_level = :debug

 # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
 # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

 # Use a different logger for distributed setups
 # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

 # Use a different cache store in production
 # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

 # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
 # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"
 # Precompile additional assets 
 config.assets.precompile += ['IEall.css']

 # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
 # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

 # Enable threaded mode
 # config.threadsafe!

 # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
 # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
   config.i18n.fallbacks = true

 # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
 config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

 # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
 # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
 # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
 end
```

### My virtualhost

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

 ServerName cg
 RailsEnv development -------------------------> if delete this line, don't work
 DocumentRoot /home/ak-48/cgs/public
 <Directory /home/ak-48/cgs/public >
 AllowOverride all
 Options -MultiViews
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I read several tutorials, but to delete the virtualhost RailsEnv development, the site displays a sign "something is wrong"

Thank!

Comment: Please, can you tell us the rails version and if 3.1+, if you're using asset pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Apache, but don't you need to replace the line `RailsEnv development` with `RailsEnv production`?

You certainly need to do something similar when you're using Nginx

Comment: @LamourdansvotrecoeurFeudansle if this answer resolved your issue, please click the check mark on the left to indicate that the question has been answered.  Thanks!